# How do I enable sound in this fresh Arch install?

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I'm following the [Arch Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide).

I have Arch running.  Now I'm working on the post-installation instructions, one of the first parts of which is to unmute the speakers. This is where my problem is.

First, I installed alsamixer.

```
pacman -S alsa-utils
```

Then unmuted master:

```
amixer sset Master unmute
```

I get this error:

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

I don't know how to proceed.

**EDIT**:

```
# cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [MID]: Hda-Intel - HDA Intel MID
         HDA Intel MID at 0xf7e14000 irq 63
1 [PCH]: Hda-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
         HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 59 

# amixer -c1 sset Master unmute
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Limits: Playback 0 - 87
Mono: Playback 60 [69%] [-20.25dB] [on]

# speaker-test -c 2

speaker-test 1.9.27.2

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`?

Comment: @EliasProbst I've updated the question with that info.

Comment: Ok, it looks like your MIDI-Controller is Card#0, so try `amixer -c1 sset Master unmute` instead.

Comment: @EliasProbst Ok I tried that.  I updated the question with the output.

Comment: "MID" is not MIDI, but stands for "Mobile Internet Device". It's the audio part of the HDMI output of the CPU's internal GPU.

Comment: Why are you using `-c 2` and not `-c 1`?

Comment: @CL."speaker-test -c 2 -D plughw:1" works, and it also works with "-c 2".

Comment: @KorganRivera Sorry, I got confused about those `-c` parameters.

Answer (score 30):

When setting up a new Arch install I usually do the following:

```
pacman -S alsa-utils
```

Then fire up alsamixer with

```
alsamixer
```

Go to 'Master' then press <kbd>M</kbd> and then keep hitting the up key to bring the sound levels up. I do that for any other inputs I want like pcm etc.

Then do

```
speaker-test -c2
```

with the number being how many channels you want to test. You should hear static from each channel in turn.

Answer (score 20):

I recommend [asoundconf](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/asoundconf/), which will take care of generating a proper `.asoundrc` .

1. List the available sound cards:

   `asoundconf list`
2. Set the default one:

   `asoundconf set-default-card PARAMETER`
3. Unmute it if necessary through either `alsamixer`(ncurses) or `amixer` (cli)

Comment: This saved me much time :D

Comment: This is without a doubt the easiest way to get that overly complex system to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the HDMI output as the default output device, and if are using PulseAudio, select the "PCH" card as the default card in PulseAudio.

For pure ALSA applications, add the following to `/etc/asound.conf` or your `~/.asoundrc`:

```
defaults.ctl.card PCH
defaults.pcm.card PCH
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do to enable audio is:

```
pacman -Sy alsa-utils pulseaudio
```

This is all you need to do to enable sound in a fresh install, I recommend installing pulseaudio as in the recent update of firefox it has dropped support for alsa, making pulseaudio a hard dependency(I think many more might follow).

If however you want to use alsa alone and are willing to switch to browsers which support alsa(I think chromium does) for the *principle*.

```
pacman -Sy alsa-utils
```

Edit /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
  device 0
}
ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
  device 0
}
```

To get the device check the output of `aplay -l` and if you select sound card in `alsamixer` (F6 to select) you would be able to manipulate the sound settings of the device and don't forget to unmute the devices' master volume